# Using $each with $push on all fields in python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a python dictionary representing updates to be made to a mongo document:

```
{
    '1': [{'x': 21, 'y': 37}, {'x': 12, 'y': 41}],
    '2': [{'x': 17, 'y': 19}, {'x': 82, 'y': 31}],
    ...
    ...
    'r2': [{'x': 21, 'y': 37}, {'x': 12, 'y': 41}]
    ...
    ...
}
```

Fields can be many, I have shown just '1', '2' and 'r1' for simplicity.
I want to push all the values in the various arrays to their respective fields in a document already in mongo (using a field 'dated', which I have in a variable).

For ex: If the document in the db was:

```
{
    '1': [{'x': 47, 'y': 33}]
    ...
}
```

After update, it should become:

```
{
    '1': [{'x':47, 'y': 33}, {'x': 21, 'y': 37}, {'x': 12, 'y': 41}]
    ...
}
```

I do not want to use $pushAll because the mongodb documentation says that its [deprecated](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/#up._S_pushAll). So how do I use $push with $each (or some other operator) on every dictionary key whose value is an array (in python 2.7 using pymongo)?

EDIT:

1. I am finding the document using a field 'dated' which is of the form 'dd-mm-yyyy'.
2. If in a document a field does not exists it should be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`collection.find_one_and_update`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) in  Pymongo 3.x or [**`collection.find_and_modify`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify)(DEPRECATED).

```
d = {                  
    '1': [{'x': 21, 'y': 37}, {'x': 12, 'y': 41}],
    '2': [{'x': 17, 'y': 19}, {'x': 82, 'y': 31}]}

for k, v in d.items():
    col.find_and_modify({k: {"$exists": True}}, {"$push": {k: {"$each": v}}})
```

---

Pymongo 3.x

```
for k, v in d.items():
    col.find_one_and_update({k: {"$exists": True}}, {"$push": {k: {"$each": v}}})
```

---

Edit:

Use the [**`update_many`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) with `upsert=True` or [**`update`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) with `upsert = True` and `multi = True` perform an insert if no documents match your filter. However you will need to iterate through each `key` to update **existing document**

```
if col.count() > 0:
    col.insert(d)
else:
    # your_update
```

Comment: But this will mean that for every key, I am executing a separate mongo query. Wouldn't a single query be more efficient than multiple? Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: I am trying to update one document in my collection. What will you like to if key doesn't exist? and since you what to `$push` value to array not `$set` you will need multiple query